# Write to virtual serial port

Tags: serial-port, driver

I created a virtual serial port driver (user mode driver using microsoft sample)and installed it to get COM3. TeraTerm application started and opened COM3. How to send data from another application to receive it in TereTerm?

Comment: If COM3 were a physical port with Teraterm attached to itt, how would you send/receive data to/from it?

Comment: Actually i wand to send send data from driver so that it will be received in TeraTerm. But inside driver, CMyQueue::OnWrite, CMyQueue::OnRead never get called. But CMyQueue::OnDeviceIoControll invoked.

Comment: My point was that if you had a physical connector for COM3, you would plug a null model cable into it, wired to another COM port, and run a program on that other COM port. Rather like com0com http://com0com.sourceforge.net/